# Writing a First-Order Language for a Basketball League

Tags: first-order-logic

Here is exercise 4 in chapter 1.2 of Leary and Kristiansen's *A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic*:

> You have been put in charge of drawing up the schedule for a basketball
>   league. This league involves eight teams, each of which must play each
>   of the other seven teams exactly two times: once at home and once
>   on the road. Think of a reasonable language for this situation. What
>   constants would you need? Do you need any relation symbols? Function
>   symbols? It would be nice if your finished schedule did not have any
>   team playing two games on the same day. Can you think of a way
>   to state this using the formal symbols that you have chosen? Can you
>   express the sentence which states that each team plays every other team
>   exactly two times?

I think this has given me more trouble than it should have. I've let the variables in the language represent, and included functions $f_0(x), \ldots, f_{13}(x)$ such that $f_a(x)$ is the team that $x$ will play against in its $a$th match. This allows me to express (with an axiom schema so cumbersome I won't write it out) the proposition that each team plays each other exactly twice.

I've also introduced for each $m \in \mathbf{N}$ 14 predicates, $D_m^0, \ldots, D_m^{13}$, defined so that $D_m^n$ is true if $x$ plays its $n$th game on day $m$. In this way I can again, with a long axiom schema, express the proposition that no team plays more than one game per day.

But I think I've made matters more complicated than they need to be. Is there a simpler approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *qualitative* relations that describe when certain general situations like "playing a game of some kind" happens. For example,

- $\mathsf{plays}(a,b,n)$ could mean "Team $a$ plays against Team $b$ during game $n$"
- $\mathsf {home(}a,n)$ could mean "Team $a$ plays a home game during game $n$"

Then you could define a constant set of teams $T = \{t_1,\ldots,t_8\}$.

You can build up to the condition "Every team plays against each other team exactly twice; once at home and once away" by breaking it into simpler components:

- The condition that everyone plays a game is: $\forall t \in T\;\;\; \exists u \in T, n\in N : \mathsf{plays}(t,u,n)$.
- The condition that every team plays against every other team is: $\forall t \neq u \in T, \exists n : \mathsf{plays}(t,u,n)$.
- The condition "$a$ plays against $b$, twice once home, once away" can be expressed in everyday language as: "There exist two games, $H$ and $A$. $H$ is a home game between $a$ and $b$, $A$ is an away game between $a$ and $b$. Any other home game between $a$ and $b$ *must be* game $H$. Similarly for $A$".

  $$f(a,b) \equiv \exists H,A :\\ \mathsf{plays}(a,b,H) \wedge \mathsf{plays}(a,b,A)\wedge \\ \mathsf{home}(a,H)\wedge \neg \mathsf{home}(a,A)\wedge \\
  \forall G : \mathsf{plays}(a,b,G) \Rightarrow (G=H \;\vee\; G=A)$$
- Then the condition that this is true for all pairs of teams can be just:
  $$\forall a,b \in T \\
  a \neq b \Rightarrow 
   \exists H,A :\\ \mathsf{plays}(a,b,H) \wedge \mathsf{plays}(a,b,A)\wedge \\ \mathsf{home}(a,H)\wedge \neg \mathsf{home}(a,A)\wedge \\
  \forall G : \mathsf{plays}(a,b,G) \Rightarrow (G=H \;\vee\; G=A)$$